# Is there a way to distribute columns rather than rows in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Currently I have to calculate correlation of multiple columns of dataframe `df` with one of the other columns `target_column`. I do it the following way:

```py
corr_cols = [F.corr(col, target_column).alias(col+'_corr') for col in df.columns if col != target_column]
corrs = df.select(*corr_cols).collect()
```

As far as I understand parallelism in spark, data is distributed between partitions by rows. Each executor works around one of the partition. If it needs rows which is not included in its partition, there would be shuffle writing.

In case of correlation it would be the case for all executors for all data. It seems to almost negate effect of parallelization.

In my vision, if I am able to distribute data by columns and broadcast `target_column` to all executors, than the process would be much faster. Is it possible in pyspark?